# Unable to find handler in C# project

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Newbie to C# and Lambda.
I'm using Jetbrains rider trying to debug the below piece of code.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Amazon.Lambda.Core;
using Amazon.S3;
using Amazon.S3.Model;
using Amazon.S3.Util;

// Assembly attribute to enable the Lambda function's JSON input to be converted into a .NET class.
[assembly: LambdaSerializer(typeof(Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.SystemTextJson.DefaultLambdaJsonSerializer))]

namespace CROLambda
{
    
    public class Function
    {

        private static AmazonS3Client _sourceClient;
        private static AmazonS3Client _destinationClient;
        
        public static void Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Done");
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to run/debug the above code through Rider using the below config.
I get an error stating that it cannot find handler "Main" in the project.
Any idea?
[image]

Below is the aws-lambda-tools-defaults.json content.

```
{
  "profile": "",
  "region": "",
  "configuration": "Release",
  "template": "template.yaml",
  "function-handler": "CROLambda::CROLambda.Function::Main"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function here isn't intended to be the entry point for an application (i.e. no static `Main` method needed). That's taken care of by AWS Lambda's hosting mechanism.

You just need a standard instance method. For example:

```cs
public void FunctionHandler()
{
}
```

or

```cs
public async Task FunctionHandler()
{
}
```

There's also different context types you can accept, and then corresponding types you should return. [Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/csharp-context.html).